# Open ggplot2 chart directly into SVG-edit application in browser?

Tags: r, web-applications, svg, ggplot2

So I was thinking it would be really awesome if you could pass a basic ggplot2 plot into SVG-edit by Google and tidy it up in there rather than messing around with to much code. I'm sure this is possible but I'm interested in how I might get started with a project like this. What tools (languages) do I need? My thought was to send the basic ggplot as an SVG with some function directly into a customized version of SVG-edit I had hosted as a web app. Anyway I would appreciate any direction on this project since it would be totally awesome to have!

Comment: an interesting aspect to consider is whether the manual interaction could be  merged back if the original plot was modified from R. I've been thinking about this for a while, ideally one could combine tools such as R for data-centric graph creation, a drawing editor for layout and annotations (inkscape/illustrator/svg-edit), and perhaps even d3 / snapsvg / svg.js for animations, and have the three of them play nice together (no overwrite, but smart merge)

Comment: @baptiste thxs for your response glad to know other people are thinking of this concept. I'm certainly no software dev but I think I have enough chops to figure this out :D. Maybe we can  collaborate at some point.

Comment: I'm using the package gridSVG to create SVG files.

I also add some javascript to this charts for "interactivity". My charts are directly crafted using the grid package, but due to the fact that ggplot is based on grid, I guess this will also work in your case.

Comment: @TomMartens That's cool. I'm not looking to do any interactivity at this point mostly just changing colors adding title and axis labels stuff like that.

Comment: especially appearing more viable now with recent efforts on https://github.com/mdecorde/RSvgDevice.  fleshing out a function to open directly in illustrator/inkscape/sketch.